# About scraping location tags in Persian real states site ( sheypoor)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to create one price map for real states by scraping the data from [the sheypoor site](https://www.sheypoor.com/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86), the final map would be something like the UK land of [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-analysis-predicting-the-housing-market-using-python-eae4f9fbd4e5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc2cW.png)

So for example,  I am searching for finding the 'تهران، پرند' the below HTML codes of [this sheypoor site](https://www.sheypoor.com/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXFol.png)

`< <div class="content">   <span class="link icon-star-empty    initialized" data-save-item="398022572"></span>   <div    class="shop-logo"> <img    src="https://www.sheypoor.com/image/15652b/75x75_Fa/shop_photos/63487/Image.jpg?1624774109">    </div>   <h2>  <a    href="https://www.sheypoor.com/مهاب-مکانیک-فاز4جنوب-398022572.html">    مهاب مکانیک فاز4جنوب </a>   </h2> <p> <time datetime="2021-11-04    16:07:52.818">لحظاتی پیش</time> </p> <p> تهران، پرند </p> <div    class="to-bottom">       <p> <span    class="attr-label">رهن:</span>&nbsp; <strong    class="item-price">۴۰,۰۰۰,۰۰۰</strong>&nbsp; تومان </p>  <p> <span    class="attr-label">اجاره:</span>&nbsp; <strong    class="item-price">۱,۰۰۰,۰۰۰</strong>&nbsp; تومان </p>   <div    class="actions">    <span class="button bordered square-round small    icon-phone pull-right call flex-icon" data-loading=""    data-track="[{&quot;category&quot;:&quot;SerpLead&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;Call&quot;}]"    data-reveal-number="398022572"> تماس</span>   </div> </div> </div>`>

so I  have made one code based of [the Web scraping - Real Estate Tokyo code in kaggle site](https://www.kaggle.com/abhijeetbhilare/web-scraping-real-estate-tokyo), which could be seen at [here in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/soheilpaper/-tft-2.4-ili9341-STM32/blob/master/Real_state_url_scraper_sheypoor1.ipynb), so I guess this must be fixed in this part of the above code:

```
import pandas as pd
real_estate_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["URL", "نوع ملک","اجاره"])

urls=['https://www.sheypoor.com/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86']
import re
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    res = get_data(url)
    print (res)
    if  (re.findall('sheypoor', url)):
        
       real_estate_df = real_estate_df.append(res, ignore_index=True)
```

Also, I have some problem with **sheypoor site** which don't let access to it and I get below error (`443`):

```
https://www.sheypoor.com/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

16 frames
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fa42dffd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.sheypoor.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fa42dffd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.sheypoor.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fa42dffd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

So if possible I have asked here to have some comment for fixing the `433` error and finding the above tag of the house in the **sheypoor site** with its location.

Thanks.

Comment: can you open this url in web browser? maybe you have to change `%D8%A7%` into normal text - because your code may try to convert `%` to `%%`

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: you have problem in code which you didn't show in question. It doesn't matter if you have link to this code. We will not visit other pages. You have to put code directly in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can **scrape** your website without 433 error by providing `User-Agent` header to request. I saw in your code that you have this line `pd.DataFrame(columns=["URL", "نوع ملک","اجاره"])`, so I conclude that you want data like those columns names. I've also added a check in my code to select price `اجاره:` and not the other. I'm not sure what third column means, but it seems to me that it's real estate location name. Hope you could modify my code to fit your needs using my informations if it's not what you are looking for:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sheypoor.com/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9/%D8%B1%D9%87%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

real_estates = parsed_html.select("#serp > div > div > div > article")
for real_estate in real_estates:
    real_estate_content = real_estate.select_one("div.content")

    real_estate_url = real_estate["data-href"]
    real_estate_prices = real_estate_content.select("div.to-bottom > p")

    for real_estate_price in real_estate_prices:
        elem_to_find = b'\xd8\xa7\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1\xd9\x87:'.decode('utf-8')
        if real_estate_price.select_one("span.attr-label").text == elem_to_find:
            real_estate_price_val = real_estate_price.select_one(".item-price").text
    if not real_estate_price_val:
        print("No price found.")

    real_estate_location = real_estate_content.select_one("p:nth-of-type(2)").text
    print(real_estate_url)
    print(real_estate_price_val)
    print(real_estate_location)
```